# Limit of sequence 5

Tags: limits

I have to find limits of sequences $A_n$ and $a_n$: $a_n = \sqrt[n]{(\frac{2012}{2013})^n - (\frac{2011}{2012})^n}$, $A_1 = 17$, $A_{n+1} = a_n \cdot A_n$. I only noticed that $a_n > \frac{2012}{2013}$ but I don't know how to find upper bound.

Answer (score 4):

hint:
$(\frac{2012}{2013})  > (\frac{2011}{2012})$

therefore

$$
a_n = \sqrt[n]{(\frac{2012}{2013})^n(1 - (\frac{2011*2013}{2012^2})^n)}
$$

$$
a_n = (\frac{2012}{2013})\sqrt[n]{1 - (\frac{2011*2013}{2012^2})^n}
$$

$(\frac{2011*2013}{2012^2})<1$ so $(\frac{2011*2013}{2012^2})^n$ goes to zero.

therefore the first limit is $\frac{2012}{2013}$

Comment: What about the second one?

Comment: The second limit does exist. $L=0$.

Comment: Observe that $A_n<2012/2013$. Expand $A_{n+1}=17\prod_{1}^na_n<17(2012/2013)^n$ .

Comment: yup. chubakueno is correct. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!(+1)